# Laravel 5 echo out session variable containing html in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I did a redirect in laravel:

```
return redirect('admin')->with($returnData);
```

$returnData is a string that contains a bootstrap info div with the result from the controller. Almost everything is working except when the page loads again it shows the html on the page as if it were text, brackets and everything. If I use this:

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('error'))) {{ Session::get('error')}} @endif
```

Then it shows is as pure text. If I change it to

```
<?php if(!empty(Session::get('error'))) { echo Session::get('error'); } ?>
```

It works fine. Im ok keeping it like this but I would rather utilize Blade / Laravel as its supposed to be used so I was wondering if there is a way to have the @if statement show the rendered html and not the text version?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should use `{{!! [PHP code goes here] !!}}` to execute code. Blade templates give you that freedom to use a much more clean syntax than surrounding it with PHP tags.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would recommend returning just the error message then in your view create the div. So if you were to change the layout of the view, you would it in one place.

```
@if(Session::has('error'))
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  {{ Session::get('error')}}
</div>
@endif
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 6):

May this example will help you.
Try this

```
 @if (session('Error'))
     <div class="alert alert-success">
         {{ session('Error') }}
     </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 5):

To show the rendered HTML you should use `{!! $variable->coontent !!}` in your view, and this gonna convert your HTML text to render

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display plain text from error without any HTML entities you can simply use:

```
{{ Session::get('error') }}
```

or

```
{{ session('error') }}
```

If you have HTML entities in your variable then use:

```
{!! Session::get('error') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your blade code to following.

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('error'))) 
    {!! Session::get('error') !!} 
@endif
```